# HTML with php in sublime 3

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I am using sublime 3 unregistered and have some html code written in .php file . How can I configure sublime so that it doesn't show error for HTML

[image]

Comment: It shows the error because that line is incorrect, not because its html in a php file. You have a closing `</src>`, this is wrong.

Comment: Your title says Sublime 3 but your post says Sublime 2 :(  Not that it makes any difference to your problem as everyone has already pointed out multiple times

Comment: So dumb of me  .. :(  perhaps using sublime for first time made me ask this question

Comment: @Not really so dumb of you.  No worries, we have all made those same type of silly mistakes.  I always say it is my fingers typing faster than my brain. But sometimes the autocomplete or code suggest gets in there and does things without you noticing. That is probably what happened actually.  I don't think you actually typed it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing an error for the html there.  The error is you are not closing your `<script>` tag with `</script>` but you have got `</src>` that does not work.

I use PHP with HTML all day long. There is no need to make Sublime support using one with the other.